# Modifying a single text file in a ZIP file, in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have a ZIP file on my server.  I want to create a PHP file, loadZIP.php that will accept a single parameter, and then modify a text file within the ZIP to reflect that parameter.

So, accessing `loadZIP.php?param=blue`, will open up the zip file, and replace some text in a text file I specify with 'blue', and allow the user to download this edited zip file.

I've looked over all of the PHP ZIP functions, but I can't find a simple solution.   It seems like a relatively easy problem, and I believe I'm over thinking it.  Before I go and write some overly complex functions, I was wondering how you'd go about this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have you taken a look at PHP5's `ZipArchive` functions?

Basically, you can use [`ZipArchive::Open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php) to open the zip, then [`ZipArchive::getFromName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getfromname.php) to read the file into memory. Then, modify it, use [`ZipArchive::deleteName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-deletename.php) to remove the old file, use [`ZipArchive::AddFromString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php) to write the new contents back to the zip, and [`ZipArchive::close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-close.php):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$fileToModify = 'myfile.txt';
if ($zip->open('test1.zip') === TRUE) {
    //Read contents into memory
    $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);
    //Modify contents:
    $newContents = str_replace('key', $_GET['param'], $oldContents)
    //Delete the old...
    $zip->deleteName($fileToModify)
    //Write the new...
    $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);
    //And write back to the filesystem.
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Note ZipArchive was introduced in PHP 5.2.0 (but, ZipArchive is also available as a [PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/zip)).

Comment: Great Solution! You missed the `;` in line **7** and **9** :)

Comment: Important if you want to change a file inside a sub-folder do this `$fileToModify = "sb/fileToModify.xml"` where sb is the sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 8 you can use [ZipArchive::replaceFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.replacefile.php)

As demonstrated by this [example from the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.replacefile.php#refsect1-ziparchive.replacefile-examples):

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->replaceFile('/path/to/index.txt', 1);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```