# PHP read a text file from a directory of zip files

Tags: php, file, zip

I have a directory which contains a set of zipped files.
each of these files has foo.txt file in it.

How can I read this text file from each zip?

I know `glob` is used to list all files from the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has [an extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) that allows you to work with ZIP archives.

Note that to access that one file you don't need to unzip the whole archive. The [ZipArchive::extractTo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php) method allows you to specify what to extract.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
$zip->extractTo('my/extract/folder/', 'foo.txt');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is a nice solution, but I have a slightly different scenario, I want to download maxmind geolite2 db from "http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country-CSV.zip", now I can extract the downloaded zip file to directory, but as you know, it will give me subfolder, now how to extract ipv4 csv only?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP zip extension as:

```
foreach(glob('*.zip') as $zipFile) {

        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        if ($zip->open($zipFile) === TRUE) {

                // get the filename without extension.
                $filename = pathinfo($zipFile,PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                // extract.
                $zip->extractTo($filename);
                $zip->close();
                echo "Extracted contents of $zipFile to $filename","\n";
        } else {
                echo "Failed to open $zipFile","\n";   
        }
}
```

Comment: Why would you extract the whole archive?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know compressed data can't be accessed this way, and you'd have to unzip it first.

If you're comfortable though, you can use this PHP extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: You have to unzip it. But not the whole archive. You can unzip only the needed file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at P[HP5's `ZipArchive` functions?](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

```
// you could extract the txt-file only and read in the content afterwards
$value = 'myzipfile.zip';
$entry = $zip->getNameIndex('foo.txt');
                copy('zip://'.dirname(__FILE__).'/zip_files/'.$value.'#'.$entry, 'txt_files/'.$value.'.txt');
} 
$zip->close();

// now you can access the file and do with the content what everyou like
```

A helpfull [SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085333/modifying-a-single-text-file-in-a-zip-file-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085333/modifying-a-single-text-file-in-a-zip-file-in-php)