# In PHP - Overwrite Specific File in Zip Folder

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm a noob at php. Trying to write a cron job script that launches a php file to overwrite a text file in a zip folder. I thought I could unzip the folder, store it in a temp folder, update the file, rezip the folder and overwrite the original zip with it. However I'm super stuck. Any guidance would be much appreciated. If it's possible to do this without extracting the zip I'm completely open to it.

Here is my code so far...

```
<?php
$tenDayDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+10 days'));
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$template = 'U-rB%%MONTH%%P%%DAY%%jn9g4NcL7DTv%%YEAR%%BPxy11wl';

function tenDayUpdate($tenDayDate, $zip, $template){

   
    $tenDayExplode = explode('-', $tenDayDate);
    $datesArray = array($tenDayExplode[1],$tenDayExplode[2],$tenDayExplode[0]);
    $wildcardArray = array("%%MONTH%%", "%%DAY%%", "%%YEAR%%");
    $tenDayLicense = str_replace($wildcardArray, $datesArray, $template);

    
   try{
        // unzip file
        $res = $zip->open('tendaylicense.zip');
        // Check if file is there
        if ($res === TRUE){
            // Extract to temp folder
            $zip->extractTo('./temp','program/testkey.txt');
            $zip->close();
            echo ' ok ' . "\n";
        } else {
            return 'failed, code' . $res;
        }
        // Update license with current date plus 10 days //
        $tempLicenseFile = './temp/program/testkey.txt';
        file_put_contents($tempLicenseFile, $tenDayLicense);
        
       //zip up folder and replace old zip ??

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }     
}

// Call Functions
tenDayUpdate($tenDayDate, $zip, $licenseTemplate);
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085464/231316

Comment: Use the [`replacefile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.replacefile.php) option of ZIP::Archive.

Comment: @Dave, please note that `ZipArchive::replaceFile` is only available since PHP8, which is _not stable_ yet!

Comment: Ha, so it is. PHP 8 is very stable. Been using it since Beta 1 and it goes GA next Thursday.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes thank you for that link,  it works without extracting and in far less code!